# Make the <a> tag open two URLs (in two different pages)

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I wanted to make the  tag open two URLs at the same time. This is what I tried:

Only HTML

```
<a href="URL1" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('URL2');">text</a>
```

This did work but not the way I wanted it to. It would open the URL2 when clicked on it and if opened in a new tab with right click or the mouse wheel it would open URL1. I want it to open both pages in new tabs at the same time.

HTML + JavaScript
HTML:

```
<a id="myId">text</a>
```

JS:

```
myId.onclick = function(){
open('https://www.example1.com');
location.href = ('https://www.example2.com');
}
```

This didn't work at all.

Comment: I think there might be something in the browser itself which prevents this? --- I just tried `<a href="https://google.com" onclick="window.open('https://bing.com')" target="_blank">HTML + JavaScript
HTML:</a>` and it works?

Comment: Works on safari, not on chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/njxz26us/3/show

Answer (score 4):

> This is Your code :

```
     myId.onclick = function(){
        open('https://www.example1.com');
        location.href = ('https://www.example2.com',,'_blank');
      }
```

> Change the code to:

```
    myId.onclick = function(){ 
      window.open('https://www.example1.com','_blank');  //just use window.open() for both the cases;
      window.open('https://www.example2.com','_blank');
    }
```

> Hope, you have got the solution for your problem.

Comment: Oh then the tutorial I saw it from must have been outdated. Anyway, I know that this way will open 1 new tab and the second URL will be opened in the current one. Is there a way to make both URLs to open in two different tabs?

Comment: @Hilex23 just use optional parameter for new tab : `window.open('https://www.example1.com', '_blank');` instead.

Comment: There's a problem though, the website doesn't recognize the <a> tag if it doesn't have an href attribute in it. So when I click on it it's like I'm clicking normal text, I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @Hilex23, it works even though if there is no href attribute.

Comment: It should, it doesn't for me though.
It should look like this: https://ibb.co/8mvGXNW
But it actually looks like this: https://ibb.co/BqfQctY
Sure, I can change the color by adding the class but it doesn't redirect to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an onclick function that uses [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to open the two URLs:

```js
document.querySelector("#foo").onclick = function () {
  window.open("https://www.example.com", "_blank");
  window.open("https://www.example.com", "_blank");
};
```

```html
<a id="foo">bar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I would suggest following.
Also look at the fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/vbhmpwe5/)

```
<a href="#" id="myId">Open Two URLs</a>

var myId = document.getElementById("myId");
myId.onclick=function(){
  window.open("https://www.google.com","_blank");
  window.open("https://www.microsoft.com","_blank");
}
```

**You should be allowing your browser's *POPUP BLOCKER* to allow opening multiple pages/tabs for this to work.**